# Can't stop Bootstrap Carousel from sliding

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-carousel

I'm using a Bootstrap 3.4.1 Carousel. I tried to prevent it from sliding with JavaScript, but this did not work with an onClick Event, although the event handler is executed. But typing $("#eventCarousel").carousel('pause'); in console stops the carousel from sliding.
I also tried using data-attributes, but that didn't help either.

This is My HTML

```
<div class="col">
    <h2 class="eventsHeading">Events </h2>
        <div id="eventCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
          <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="3"></li>
          </ol>
          <div class="carousel-inner">
            
          </div>
          <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#eventCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="icon-rl-Arrow" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
          </a>
          <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#eventCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="icon-rl-Right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
          </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is my Javascript, which is called on document.ready to fill the slider with data.

```
function createSliderContent(response, Domain){
    for(let i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        
            /*** Create image 
        let imgSrc = domain + response.events[i].eventWebImageSmallUrl;
        let image = document.createElement("img");
        image.className = "sliderImage lazyload";
        image.src = "";
        image.setAttribute('data-src', imgSrc);
        image.alt = "";
        **/
        let imageWrapper = document.createElement("div");
        imageWrapper.className = "imageWrapper";
        
        let image = document.createElement("img");
        image.className = "sliderImage";
        image.src = domain + response.events[i].eventWebImageSmallUrl;
        image.alt = "";
        
        let carouselItem = document.createElement("div");
        carouselItem.className = "carousel-item";
        
        let cardWrapper = document.createElement("div");
        cardWrapper.className = "cardWrapper";
        
        let contentWrapper = document.createElement("div");
        contentWrapper.className = "contentWrapper";
        
        let cardHeader = document.createElement("h4");
        cardHeader.className = "cardHeader";
        $(cardHeader).html(response.events[i].name);
        
        let cardDescription = document.createElement("p");
        cardDescription.className = "cardDescription";
        $(cardDescription).html(response.events[i].description);
        
        let buttonWrapper = document.createElement("div");
        buttonWrapper.className = "buttonWrapperMobile";
        
        let moreButton = document.createElement("a");
        moreButton.className = "moreButton button btn_orange";
        $(moreButton).html("more");
        $(moreButton).attr("href", "");
        
        let showFormButton = document.createElement("a");
        showFormButton.className = "showFormButtonSlider button btn_orange";
        if(!eventIsSoldOut(response.events[i])){
            $(showFormButton).html("Booking");
        }else{
            $(showFormButton).html("Waitinglist");
        }
        $(showFormButton).attr('id', 'item' + i);
        
        $(imageWrapper).append(image);
        $(cardWrapper).append(imageWrapper);
        $(contentWrapper).append(cardHeader);
        $(contentWrapper).append(cardDescription);
        $(buttonWrapper).append(moreButton);
        if(response.events[i].bookable){
            $(buttonWrapper).append(showFormButton);
        }
        $(contentWrapper).append(buttonWrapper);
        $(cardWrapper).append(contentWrapper);
        $(carouselItem).append(cardWrapper);
        $("#eventCarousel .carousel-inner").append(carouselItem);
        
    }
    $("#eventCarousel .carousel-item").first().addClass("active"); // add class active to first slider element to start slider

};
```

Now clicking on button "showFormButtonSlider" should stop the slider from sliding with following code, but noting happens.

```
$(document).on("click", ".showFormButtonSlider", function(){
    $("#eventCarousel").carousel('pause');
});
```

Comment: Put data-interval="0" on element with id="eventCarousel".

Comment: Where is your carousel initialized? Are you creating that event handler after that?